# JavaScript How to arr.join() for array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I wonder what is the best way to join items of array into one string. I know that there array.join() for this. And it works perfect for even array of arrays

For ex.

```
let arr=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
console.log(arr.join(''));
```

```
abcdef
```

but what about

```
let arr=[['abc',1],['def',2]]
console.log(arr.join(''));
```

```
abc,1,def,2
```

So my question is what is the best way to join only first element of array of arrays mean abc of each element skipping the second element to produce `'abcdef'` string from `[['abc',1],['def',2]]` array?

Comment: is it really javascript?

Comment: That's not the Javascript syntax to create an array. `console,log` probably compiles (if you have a `log` function in your scope), but likely not what you wanted

Comment: how about `arr.map((x,y) => x[0]).join('')`

Comment: "abcdef]"? Is the closing bracket significant in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming valid JavaScript:

```
let arr=[['abc',1],['def',2]];
```

If you only need the first element of each nested array, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array which only contains the first elements, then join the new array:

```
console.log(arr.map(a => a[0]).join(''));
```

Comment: but doesn't `arr.join()` do this without requiring the map call? I'm not sure this is what OP wants

Comment: @cs95 Oh, thanks. I misread the question. I thought joining all elements was the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to join the elements in one iteration:

```js
const arr = [["abc", 1], ["def", 2]];

const result = arr.reduce((str, [first]) => `${str}${first}`, "");

console.log(result); // "abcdef"
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming right array syntax ,
const fruits = [["Banana", "Orange1"], ["Apple", "Mango"]];

Use [Array.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) , it will return comma separated array values

const fruits = [["Banana", "Orange1"], ["Apple", "Mango"]];
let text = fruits.toString();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).